# how to access value of physical memory and store the value via making file in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, memory, kernel

I'm a kernel newbie and have a bad English.

I have an STM32 board. STM32 board has a unique Id.

I want to access a physical memory address that stores unique Id and takes a value of the address.

And then I want to store value to buffer because of making files consist of unique Id.

My final Destination is making a file that contains the Unique Id of the board.

Below is my code.

```
u8 buf_uniqueId[12];
void __iomem *Unique_Id = ioremap(0x5C005234, 12);

if(Unique_Id == NULL){
    printk(KERN_INFO "count not found UniqueId\n");
    return 1;
}

printk(KERN_INFO "This is UniqueId\n");


struct file *unique = filp_open("/Unique_Id", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644);

if(unique == -1){
    printk("[!] Can't crate the dstfile");
    return 2;
}
else{
    fs = get_fs();
    set_fs(get_ds());
    for(i=0;i<12;i++){
        buf_uniqueId[i]=readb(Unique_Id+i);
        
        printk(KERN_DEBUG "value of buffer is %02x\n", buf_uniqueId[i]);
        printk("%02x ", readb(Unique_Id+i));
    }
    vfs_write(unique, buf_uniqueId, strlen(buf_uniqueId), &unique->f_pos);
}
```

The reading value of physical memory works well.

But storing the value to the buffer is failed.

Please give me advice.

Thank you.

Comment: "But storing the value to the buffer is failed." - What does this mean? Do you got an error? Or fault? Or the output file contains wrong values? Please, update the question post and elaborate the problem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I got no error. But when I printed buffer, anything is printed.

Comment: I don't see in your code a line which prints the buffer's content. You printing the values read by `readb` and stores buffer into the file (and content of that file could be extracted e.g. with `cat`). So, which exact print gives unexpected result?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry my mistake. I edit my post.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm sorry. printing value of buffer is a success. The problem is strlen() function in vfs_write(). Now all of problems are resolved. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the definition for `buf_uniqueId` is missing, storing to a valid array with at least 12 elements should work OK. Consider `readb()` possibly returning a zero. Instead of calling `strlen()` and expecting a NULL-terminated string, the write size should be one of `sizeof()` or fixed at 12, depending on `buf_uniqueId` allocation. You might replace each 12 with a `#define` symbol.

Suggest removing the `get_fs()` and `set_fs()` lines, along with replacing `vfs_write()` with a call to `kernel_write()` and check the result; also note the `old_fs` restoration within `kernel_write()`

The compiler should complain about comparing pointer and integer: `(unique == -1)`; `filp_open()` could return various error codes; follow the source code from `filp_open()` to see various error related macros, eg `IS_ERR()`

Comment: I want to know the way to store the value of the address of unique_Id in the array.

Comment: Yes you are right. The problem exist on strlen(). Thank you.